# fast subsetting in data.table in R

Tags: r, join, data.table, subset

Given a `data.table`, I would like to subset the items in there *quickly*. For example:

```
dt = data.table(a=1:10, key="a")
dt[a > 3 & a <= 7]
```

This is pretty slow still. I know I can do joins to get individual rows but is there a way to fact that the `data.table` is sorted to get quick subsets of this kind?

This is what I'm doing:

```
dt1 = data.table(id = 1, ym = c(199001, 199006, 199009, 199012), last_ym = c(NA, 199001, 199006, 199009), v = 1:4, key=c("id", "ym"))
dt2 = data.table(id = 1, ym = c(199001, 199002, 199003, 199004, 199005, 199006, 199007, 199008, 199009, 199010, 199011, 199012), v2 = 1:12, key=c("id","ym"))
```

For each `id`, here there is only 1, and `ym` in `dt1`, I would like to sum the values of `v2` between current `ym` in `dt1` and the last `ym` in `dt1`. That is, for `ym == 199006` in `dt1` I would like to return `list(v2 = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)`. These are the values of `v2` in `dt2` that are equal to or less than the current `ym` (excluding the previous ym).  In code:

```
expr = expression({ #browser();
 cur_id = id; 
 cur_ym = ym; 
 cur_dtb = dt2[J(cur_id)][ym <= cur_ym & ym > last_ym]; 
 setkey(cur_dtb , ym);
 list(r = sum(cur_dtb$v2))
})

dt1[,eval(expr ),by=list(id, ym)]
```

Comment: I don't see how this is slow at all? It took 0.28 sec using `system.time` on a `data.table` of 10 million rows.

Comment: yes but if you have to do this 100,000 times, that's slow! i might have to come up with a different alg for what i'm doing.

Comment: Are you using a `for` loop?

Comment: no, i'm not. let me put an example up.

Comment: Your example doesn't run at all for me. :/

Comment: sorry, let me test it. i just wrote up the code in the window here in a rush. poor practice on my part apologies.

Comment: Why do you set a key in your expression?

Comment: I'm not very skilled with data.table, but maybe `dt1[dt2,roll = -Inf]` is a potential route to go down?

Comment: @Roland: yeh the key setting is not necessary here, it is for the more extended thing i'm doing i just didnt' bother to delete it.

Comment: @Alex, I'd like to benchmark something I've tried against the current solutions. Would you mind linking to your bigger data (or generate a sample big data)? Seems a bit tricky to generate random data.

Comment: @Arun: unfortunately i can't link to the big data set, i think the best approach would be to generate some sample data randomly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the logical condition, perform a rolling join of `dt1` and `dt2`.  Then shift `ym` forward by one position within `id`.  Finally, sum over `v2` by `id` and `ym`:

```
setkey(dt1, id, last_ym)
setkey(dt2, id, ym)
dt1[dt2,, roll = TRUE][
       , list(v2 = v2, ym = c(last_ym[1], head(ym, -1))), by = id][
       , list(v2 = sum(v2)), by = list(id, ym)]
```

Note that we want to sum everything since the `last_ym` so the key on `dt1` must be `last_ym` rather than `ym`.

The result is:

```
   id     ym v2
1:  1 199001  1
2:  1 199006 20
3:  1 199009 24
4:  1 199012 33
```

UPDATE: correction

Comment: sorry, i'm a bit confused by all the `setkey` expressions.. those don't look correct...?

Comment: I have fixed them to correspond to what I was actually using and added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the fact that `data.table` is sorted, you will be limited to the amount of time it takes to evaluate `a > 3 & a <= 7` in the first place:

```
> dt = data.table(a=1:10000000, key="a")
> system.time(dt$a > 3 & dt$a <= 7)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.18    0.01    0.20 
> system.time(dt[,a > 3 & a <= 7])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.18    0.05    0.24 
> system.time(dt[a > 3 & a <= 7])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.07    0.31
```

Alternative approach:

```
> system.time({Indices = dt$a > 3 & dt$a <= 7 ; dt[Indices]})
user  system elapsed 
0.28    0.03    0.31
```

**Multiple Subsets**

There can be a speed issue here if you break up factors on an ad hoc basis rather than doing it all at once first:

```
> dt <- data.table(A=sample(letters, 10000, replace=T))
> system.time(for(i in unique(dt$A)) dt[A==i])
   user  system elapsed 
   5.16    0.42    5.59 
> system.time(dt[,.SD,by=A])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.32    0.03    0.36
```

Comment: just posted an example, maybe you can think of a better way to do this